# Hammer Throw Forces

Tags: centripetal-force

I have a hammer (7 kg) and chain (120 cm) that I'm using in an Olympic event.  It's a special hammer with a built-in jet that can generate 400 Newtons of thrust.  The exhaust of the jet is directed along the chain towards the person holding the chain (me).  The chain itself is only tested for 375 Newtons.  If I turn the jets on while the ball is not rotating, the chain breaks.  What happens to the chain if I turn the jets on while swinging this ball in a circle at 10 m/s?

Comment: I don't think you'll get the chance to find out empirically, the IOC is fairly strict about equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It breaks before you have a chance to turn the jet on: $(7\,\mathrm{kg}) (10\,\mathrm{m/s})^2 / (1.2\,\mathrm{m}) = 583\,\mathrm{N}$ which must be supplied by the chain (tension being the centripetal force in this case).

Comment: OK, the chain is slightly elastic but will break if 375 Newtons is applied for more than 30 seconds, which is enough time to get the ball up it's velocity of 10 m/s. What happens to the chain when the jet is turned on?

Comment: It breaks even faster. The geometry of the motion still sets the net radial force to by $583\,\mathrm{N}$, but now the tension has to cancel out the thrust *and* provide the addition inward component $T - t = mv^2/r$ so $T = t + mv^2/r$.

Comment: To illustrate my confusion, could you tell me what is wrong with this sum of forces equation?$$F_c = -m\frac{v^2}{r}\hat{r} = -T_{CHAIN}\hat{r} + F_{JET}\hat{r}$$The unit vector $\hat{r}$ is directed outward.

Comment: Now that I look at it, nothing is wrong with the equation as we both agree with the final scalar form.  Could it be that I'm still having trouble with the centripetal force concept?  Is the tension on the chain greater but the centripetal force felt by the ball is less?